# In the case of uncountable nouns, can I use them as a plural without adding an “s”?

Tags: sentence-construction

I was looking in the dictionary and these two phrases caught my eye:

1. Exercise is a good way to get physical exercise
2. I do stomach exercises most days

As you can see, exercise were used in both sentences as a plural, once with “s” and once without it
My question is, in the case of uncountable nouns, can I use them as a plural without adding an “s”?

Comment: Please [cite the source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) of the sentences that you've quoted. (I'm especially interested because the first sentence seems very unusual for a dictionary example, so I wonder how it was presented.)

Answer (score 1):

In the first, "exercise" is uncountable and treated as singular.  It is not a plural. It isn't "used as a plural".  There is nothing plural about it.  Uncountable nouns are sometimes called "mass nouns" as the refer to a mass of something, instead of one or many individual items. It refers to the set of movements and activities.  In the same way that "rice" is uncountable, and refers the the set of grains.

Of course, the first sentence is nonsense, or at best a tautology.

The second sentence uses "exercise" as a countable and plural noun.  It means many individual exercises.